# LockerService and Lightning.out.js in Visualforce

Tags: lightning, locker-service

I've got a Lightning component, version 38.0.  It works fine inside Communities.  It does not work fine as a Lightning out app in Visualforce.  I'm getting what appear to me to be LockerService errors -- "Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'name' of component is not visible" etc.    I was able to reproduce these errors with the component in Communities by changing the version to 41.0.   (Obviously, I have changed it back!)

I have checked the version of the containing VF page, the Lightning out app, and all controllers, and they're all under 40.0.  The only thing that I can think of remaining as an issue is the lightning.out.js script.  Does the Lightning.out script itself enforce Locker Service?  If so, is there a way to get a previous version of the lightning.out.js script?

Comment: you would want to fix the issue rather than using than v38.0 version of the code .

Comment: Hi Mohith-- I understand in the long term, it's best to fix the issue.  My question is about the short term-- is it possible to use a prior version of the lightning.out.js script?

Comment: Lightning.out does not enforce Locker Service. The API version of your custom components will decide wether is Locker Service is On(>V39.0) or Off. It sounds like you probably encountered a bug in the api version caching on our end(we have a bug logged for it). When u change the version of your components, touch the markup of the component by adding a space and save the component. That should make fetch the right component api version.

Comment: If you actively develop components - disable "Secure and persistent browser cacheing" in Session Settings.